# How to see google protobuf log?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, protocol-buffers

The cause:

1. I use protobuf dll link because I want my dll small.
2. I load my dll using windows API LoadLibrary() and it returns 1114(ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED).
3. I try to use Procmon to figure out what happened.
4. I see something like this in call stack:

> "16","ntdll.dll","RtlRaiseException + 0x2d9","0x7ffe5b0eb629","C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
>
> "17","KernelBase.dll","RaiseException + 0x68","0x7ffe58443c58","C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll"
>
> "18","vcruntime140.dll","CxxThrowException + 0xc2","0x7ffe433c4462","C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll"
>
> "19","libprotobuf.dll","google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::Finish + 0x128","0x7ffe39206ed8","C:\Program Files......\libprotobuf.dll"
>
> "20","libprotobuf.dll","google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile + 0xd1","0x7ffe392541d1","C:\Program Files......\libprotobuf.dll"

The fact:

1. If I use protobuf static link, this problem vanished.
2. protobuf version is 3.0.0

Question:

Is it possible to see the log of google protobuf?
I want to know the root cause.

Comment: If it works with static but not dynamic, then one possibility is it can't find the dll. Is the dll in the same folder as your executable when you try to run it?

Comment: I think it already finds the libprotobuf.dll because it shows the path in the call stack.

Comment: Protobuf logs messages to standard error. If you run your program as a console application, you should see any messages on the console.